# Laravel 5.0 Application Structure

Tags: laravel, interface, architecture, laravel-5

I'm building a RESTful API using Laravel 5.

Trying to keep the Http controllers to being as minimal as possible, so I'm using a Service layer (and Repositories) to handle most of the logic.

As most of the controllers have similar methods (e.g. `show`, `index`, `update`) I've written some traits that handle each one. Because these talk directly to the service, I can reuse these for each controller.

For example:

```
<?php namespace API\Http\Controllers\Restful;

trait UpdateTrait
{
    protected $updater;

    public function update($itemID)
    {
        if (!$this->updater->authorize($itemID)) {
            return response(null, 401);
        }

        if (!$this->updater->exists($itemID)) {
            return response(null, 404);
        }

        $data = $this->request->all();
        $validator = $this->updater->validator($data);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response($validator->messages(), 422);
        }

        $this->updater->update($itemID, $data);

        return response(null, 204);
    }
}
```

Because all the controllers share the same traits they can all depend on a single interface.

For example:

```
<?php namespace API\Services\Interfaces;

interface UpdaterServiceInterface
{
    public function validator(array $data);
    public function exists($itemID);
    public function update($itemID, array $data);
    public function authorize($itemID);
}
```

However, this causes a few issues with automatic dependency injection.

1) I have to use context aware binding:

```
$this->app->when("API\Http\Controllers\ThingController")
          ->needs("API\Services\Interfaces\UpdateServiceInterface")
          ->give("API\Services\Things\ThingUpdateServiceInterface")
```

This isn't problematic in and of itself - although it does lead to some rather large Service Provider code, which isn't ideal. However, it means I can't seem to use method injection, as the **automatic dependency resolution doesn't seem to work for controller methods when using context aware binding**: I just get back a `could not instantiate API\Services\Interfaces\UpdateServiceInterface` message.

This means that the controller constructor has to handle all of the dependency injection, which gets quite messy:

```
class ThingsController extends Controller
{
    use Restful\IndexTrait,
        Restful\ShowTrait,
        Restful\UpdateTrait,
        Restful\PatchTrait,
        Restful\StoreTrait,
        Restful\DestroyTrait;

    public function __construct(
        Interfaces\CollectionServiceInterface $collection,
        Interfaces\ItemServiceInterface $item,
        Interfaces\CreatorServiceInterface $creator,
        Interfaces\UpdaterServiceInterface $updater,
        Interfaces\PatcherServiceInterface $patcher,
        Interfaces\DestroyerServiceInterface $destroyer
    ) {
        $this->collection = $collection;
        $this->item = $item;
        $this->creator = $creator;
        $this->updater = $updater;
        $this->patcher = $patcher;
        $this->destroyer = $destroyer;
    }
}
```

This isn't good - it's hard to test and all those dependencies have to get instantiated, even when only one of them is being used.

But I can't think of a nicer way round it.

I could use more specific interface, e.g. `ThingUpdateServiceInterface`, (then I wouldn't need the contextual binding and could inject directly into the traits), but then I'd have lots of interfaces that are only different in name. Which seems daft.

The other alternative I thought of was to use lots of smaller controllers, so a `Things\UpdateController` and a `Things\ShowController` - at least that way unnecessary dependencies won't get instantiated every time.

Or maybe trying to abstract away to using traits is the wrong way to do things. Traits do sometimes seem like they're potentially an anti-pattern.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for nice detailed question. How about creating `UpdateService` with the code in your UpdateTrait and type-hint it in your RESTful update method, like `public function update($itemID, UpdateService)` I have not tested this dough but I think it can be don't. You might have issue in your tests if you continue with what you have so far

Comment: In L5 you can do what is called Method Injection see [here](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/laravel-5.0-method-injection) further more, I would create authorization middleware + "exists" middleware, and use request class as much as possible. Traits are nice abstraction of code, but later you are going to face problems I think simply because so far application is "not complex", time goes by and app gets more and more complex so you are going to need "unique" updater, patcher perhaps destroyer (lets say you do some M:N relations). What about creating RestfullController? And do some extending?

Comment: - Method injection doesn't work when you're using contextual binding, or at least I can't get it to.
- I don't want to create a single RestfulController and extend because quite a few of them won't use most the methods (e.g. some only have `index` and `show`).
- I'm using auth middleware already, but still makes sense to have it in the service as well I think (e.g. if using the service for Console instead of HTTP)

Comment: There seems to be several [issues](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/6177) opened regarding contextual binding and method injection, but there is no solution until now. This is a bug and I hope it will be fixed anytime soon. You can open new issue in git issues tracking, let's hope we draw the attention of Taylor.

Comment: I think if contextual binding worked on the methods then it would all be quite neat. Maybe that's all it comes down to.

Comment: i think a repository pattern would be nicer.

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks great and well thought to generalisation.

I would like to suggest this option for using a Factory for creating your services, and not predefine all the dependency injections.

```
interface UpdateServiceInterface {
    public function action($itemID);
    //....
}

class ThingUpdateServiceInterface implements UpdateServiceInterface {
    public function action($itemID)
    {
        // TODO: Implement exists() method.
    }
}

class ApiServiceFactory {

    protected $app;

    public function __construct(Application $app) {
        $this->app = $app;
    }

    public function getUpdateService($type) {
        if ($type == 'things')
            return $this->app->make('ThingUpdateServiceInterface');
    }

   public function getCreateService($type) {
        if ($type == 'things') {
            //same idea here and for the rest
        }
    }

}




class ApiController {

    protected $factory;
    protected $model;

    public function __construct(ApiServiceFactory $factory) {
        $this->factory = $factory;
    }

    public function update($data) {
        $updater = $this->factory->getUpdateService($this->model);
        $updater->action($data);
    }
}

class ThingsController extends ApiController {
    protected $model = 'App\Thing';
}
```

what is the idea of all of this is:

- basic ApiController that holds all the methods: update, insert, delete...
- each other controller for specific object will extend the api controller and override the $model with the Model full name.
- in the action of the controller it uses the factory for creating the service for that specific object.
- after creation of the service it uses it for the action desired.
- you could create general action for the action, like

  ```
  DeleteServiceInterface
  ```

will be implemented by

```
    class GeneralDeleteService implements DeleteServiceInterface {
           public function delete($id){......}
    }
```

and in the factory when you request for that DeleteService if no name is passed so you will return the default service

hope this post wont be "TLDR"